# Is micropython supported?

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have quite a collection of Arduinos but I always dread programming them.  It takes so much effort to do simple things.

Is anyone working on rosserial for Micropython boards?  That would be a wonderful solution for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267490/is-micropython-supported?/) by [kylerlaird](https://answers.ros.org/users/23170/kylerlaird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i  know it is three years to late but i just found some rosserial support.

https://pypi.org/project/micropython-rosserial/

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I still like the idea of using rosserial and Micropython, but lately I've been using [Firmata](https://github.com/MrYsLab/FirmataExpress) and [Pymata](https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata4).  For some projects I can make few or no modifications to the Firmata code running on the Arduino.  That leaves the programming on the main computer, which is where I'd rather have it unless I have something time-critical to run.

---

Originally posted by [kylerlaird](https://answers.ros.org/users/23170/kylerlaird/) with karma: 104 on 2020-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1